# Sum of two counts in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

This query works fine but looks redundant (maybe I'm wrong). It exist a better way to do this?
(I need all the 4 columns with the total for every row)

```
 select parz.*, (parz.sessioniSvolte + parz.sessioniPianificate ) as sessioniTotale
 from (
    select 
      e.Prefettura AS Prefettura, 
      count(case when  s.Giorno<getDate() then    s.idSessione else null end) AS sessioniSvolte,
      count(case when  s.Giorno>=getDate() then    s.idSessione else null end) AS sessioniPianificate
        from SESSIONE_FORMAZIONECIVICA s
        inner join SEDE_SESSIONECIVICA e ON e.idSede = s.idSede

        GROUP BY e.Prefettura
) as parz
```

I founded similar questions, but they didn't match with my problem.

Comment: It really does help if you translate your query into english, you and my pig latin now have me wondering about swelty sessions, and sessions made of bread.

Comment: sessioniSvolte = madeSessions
sessioniPianificate = plannedSession :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query may be rewritten without the subquery by adding a simple `count(*)`:

```
select 
  e.Prefettura AS Prefettura, 
  count(case when s.Giorno<getDate() then s.idSessione end) AS sessioniSvolte,
  count(case when s.Giorno>=getDate() then s.idSessione end) AS sessioniPianificate,
  count(*) as sessioniTotale
from SESSIONE_FORMAZIONECIVICA s
join SEDE_SESSIONECIVICA e ON e.idSede = s.idSede
GROUP BY e.Prefettura
```

I removed the redundant `else null`, because null is the default result for a case when there's no match.

Comment: Just a question, what does count(*) ? It sums all the value of a single row? For example, if in the select I had another count, this count will go in the count(*) ?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: if I had another column in my select, for example:
 count(case when foo='1' then s.idSessione end) AS count2 
what will happen to: count(*) as sessioniTotale ? It will become equal to  sessioniSvolte+sessioniPianificate+count2

Comment: Ahh. No. The reason `count(*)` is the total is that *logically* the other two counts are counting logical negatives of each other. That is, every row is either `Giorno<getDate()` *or* `Giorno>=getDate()`, so the total of these two must be the count of all the rows.